# How many characters are in the monk's alphabet?

Tags: combinations

I just read [The Nine Billion Names of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God) by [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke).

In that story, the monks estimated (or confirmed) the number of `9,000,000,000`(nine billion) for all the possible names of God with nine characters in max.

That contains, I think, (using English alphabets)

```
0          a
           b
           c
           ...
           aa
           bb
           ...
           ccc
           ...
9000000000 zzzzzzzzz (whatever the last alphabet)
```

Now how can I calculate (or estimate) the total number of the monks' alphabets whose all nine (or less) combinations counts `9,000,000,000`?

Comment: Assuming the English alphabet of $26$ letters (*case in-sensitive*), the number of possible strings of length $1$ to $9$ is equal to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 26^i\approx 5,646,000,000,000$.  If you are asking how many letters are in the monks' alphabet to have arrived at a number of approximately $9$ billion, with $12$ letters that would be approximately $5.6$ billion while with $13$ letters that would be approximately $11.5$ billion.

Comment: Oh my dear @JMoravitz, please make an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: As it is phrased, I don't think that this is really a question about mathematics---you have not sufficiently nailed down the question (are you asking "If an alphabet can spell out 9 billion words, how many letters must be in that alphabet?"  or are you asking "How many different subsets of the English alphabet can be used to spell out 9 billion words?").  Also, as I recall, Clarke suggests that not every possible combination of letters is a name of god, so only a finite subset of the possible words count---should we account for this?  How?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm sorry I'm not good in English neither in Math. I wanted to know, in a finite set of alphabets, all number of unique words, which each word's length is equals or less than `9`, (approximately) is 9 billion, how many characters required to be defined in that alphabet.

Comment: My memory is that (some / all?) letters could occur three times successively but no more.  I don't recall whether there were other constraints or whether it was claimed that there were no others.  My best guess is that the exact rules were left vague.

Comment: Oh, God. I realized I forgot the constraint. I don't know the exact literal condition of the constraint cuz I read it in Korean-translated. Can anybody please quote the constraint in original form?

Comment: I found it. `A rather more interesting problem is that of devising suitable circuits to eliminate ridiculous combinations. For example, no letter must occur more than three times in succession.”` I should've known that and mentioned that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of strings of length exactly $k$ that can be formed from an alphabet of $n$ characters is $n^k$, seen by direct application of the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

The number then of non-empty strings of length at most $k$ that can be formed from an alphabet of $n$ characters is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k n^i$

Plugging in some numbers, we have the number of possible non-empty (case-insensitive) strings using the $26$ letters from the English alphabet of length at most $9$ will be:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^9 26^i \approx 5,646,000,000,000$$

As for how many letters are in the monks' alphabet to have arrived at a value of $9$ billion, you have $12$ letters would give you approximately $5.6$ billion while $13$ letters would give you approximately $11.5$ billion possible non-empty strings of length at most $9$.

Of course, this entirely ignores certain constraints such as the number of consecutive consonants or placements of vowels and the like, so many of these strings would be unpronouncable.

Comment: So, besides those linguistic problems, there should be at least 13 characters in that alphabet, right? Thanks.

Comment: As I said in a comment to question, there was a rule that no letter occurred more than three consecutively.  I don't recall whether there were more rules.